# Python Regular Expression: replace a letter if it is not a part of the word in a list

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

Assume I have a word list like `[cat,hat,mat,ate]` and I would like to to remove all the letter `a` in a string like `acatbatmate` to `catbtmate` if the letter `a` is not in the word list.

In the current step, I can split the string by the words in the word list with the following codes:

```
''.join([word.replace('a','') 
         if word not in ['cat','hat','mat','ate'] 
         else word for word in re.split('(cat|hat|mat|ate)','acatbatmate') ])
```

Is it possible for me to use `re.sub(pattern, repl, string)` to remove the letter `a` straightforwardly?

Comment: What is the Python version?

Comment: Sorry for late reply, it's Python 3.6

Comment: Great, so to *remove*, you may just use [`re.sub(r'({})|a'.format("|".join(except_contexts)), r'\1', 'acatbatmate')`](https://ideone.com/ECT8UL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may easily do it with `re` like this:

```
import re
except_contexts = ['cat','hat','mat','ate']
print(re.sub(r'({})|a'.format("|".join(except_contexts)), lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else '', 'acatbatmate'))
# => catbtmate
```

See the [Python 2 demo](https://ideone.com/IxSvay).

If you are using Python 3.5+, it is even easier with a mere backreference:

```
import re
except_contexts = ['cat','hat','mat','ate']
print(re.sub(r'({})|a'.format("|".join(except_contexts)), r'\1', 'acatbatmate'))
```

However, if you plan to *replace* that `a`, you will need to use the lambda expression.

**Details**

`r'({})|a'.format("|".join(except_contexts))` will look like `(cat|hat|mat|ate)|a` regex. It will match and capture `cat`, `hat`, etc. into Group 1 and if it matches, we need to replace with this group contents. Else, we either replace with an empty string or a required replacement.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/V4w3m8/1).

Comment: `lambda x: x.group(1) if x.group(1) else ''` could be `lambda x: x.group(1) or ''`

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre [Right](https://ideone.com/0Fxsfv), that shortens the code a bit. However, my [`re.sub(r'({})|a'.format("|".join(except_contexts)), r'\1', 'acatbatmate')`](https://ideone.com/ECT8UL) is shorter :), it will work in Python 3.6 OP uses.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can (I've always wanted to write it like that...):

```
import regex as re

exceptions = ['cat','hat','mat','ate']
rx = re.compile(r'''(?:{})(*SKIP)(FAIL)|a+'''.format('|'.join(exceptions)))

word = rx.sub('', 'acatbatmate')
print(word)
```

This makes use of the newer `regex` module that supports `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)`.
The pattern here is:

```
(?:cat|hat|mat|ate)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)
|
a+
```

---

Without a new module, you could use a function `handler`:

```
import re

exceptions = ['cat','hat','mat','ate']

def handler(match):
    if match.group(1):
        return ''
    return match.group(0)

rx = re.compile(r'''(?:{})|(a+)'''.format('|'.join(exceptions)))

word = rx.sub(handler, 'acatbatmate')
print(word)
```

Comment: Note that requires a PyPi regex module.